# Product adds to line when field changes

Tags: odoo-8, odoo

I have button that makes field "urgent" true. So when i push that button i need that product "services" would be added to sale.order.line. 
Tried to make it this way but with no luck.

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order"

    urgent = fields.Boolean('Urgent')

    @api.multi
    def urgent_activate(self):
        self.urgent = True

    @api.onchange('urgent')
    def urgent_onchange(self):
        if self.urgent:
            vals = {
                'name': 'test',
                'product_id': 1
            }
        self.order_line.write(vals)
```

Comment: I guess there is some problem with the syntax. It should be self.write('order_lines':[(0,0,{'name':'test', 'product_id':1})]) as we are adding new columns to the sale order line.
You can visit CRUD operations on the given link https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#model-reference

Comment: your syntax is have some problems to. self.order_line.write('order_lines': [(0,0,{'name':'test', 'product_id':1})])
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: it shouldn't be "self.order_line.write". It should be self.write(...)

Comment: no error now, but still order line is empty

Comment: It's order_line instead of order_lines. Please update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following code:

```
@api.multi
def urgent_activate(self):
    self.urgent = True
    vals = {
        'name': 'test',
        'product_id': 1,
        'order_id':self.id
    }
    self.order_line.create(vals)
```

About your comment... maybe something like this

```
@api.multi
def urgent_activate(self):
    self.urgent = True

    for order_line in self.order_line:
        if order_line.name == 'Services':               
            vals = {
                'name': 'test',
                'product_id': 1,
                'order_id':self.id
            }
            self.order_line.write(order_line.id,vals)
```

I dont test this second part, let me know if works

Comment: Thank you for you answer. one more question. if i have product that's name is "Services" how can i add it in this line, instead of creating new vals?